# Lambda, SQS and Cloudwatch - Architectural question

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, aws-lambda, bigdata, amazon-sqs

I have an interesting real-life situation:

- I have a huge SQS (with really plenty of messages, constantly refilling (worst-case scenario, 50 messages per second);
- A Lambda that will consume SQS and push them to an external database (the database will process the messages in a sync way, unfortunately).

**Constraints:**

- The final external database shouldn't process data continuously but needs some idle time. This is due to the database activity costs (cost per CPU usage);
- SQS is already part of the architecture;
- the final external database is not in my control.

**Here are my solutions, concerns and questions:**

- Sol 1: Using Cloudwatch to schedule the Lambda every hour to give time to consume part of the queue and then leaving the final DB idle for a bit.

Issue: the queue could "explode" meaning it could fill really quickly and the processing would be slow.

- Sol 2: Create a Lambda (A) triggered by Cloudwatch every X time. This Lambda would cycle 10 times and trigger another Lambda (B) that would consume 10 messages (max of msgs per "time?" in SQS) and should autoscale as well.

Issue: Not sure about the autoscaling criteria... it looks more fantasy.

- Sol 3 (bonus): Create a second SQS (2). An intermediate Lambda (I) will be triggered every X time and move the messages from SQS (1) to SQS (2). There is an event on SQS (2) that will trigger a Lambda (2) and this will autoscale.

Issue: too messy, overcomplicated, tied to the number of messages moved from SQS (1) to SQS (2).

**Now**

Now, it is clear my concern is related to the Lambda autoscaling in consuming SQS and feeding the database.
Also, the Lambda should scale enough to consume a good amount of SQS messages but, at the same time, should leave some idle time to the final database.

I hope I've explained the situation well and would be happy to have your advice on that (happy to learn!).

Thanks,
Mauro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would leverage the [Lambda Reserved Concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/per-function-concurrency.html).

1. It limits the max concurrency for the lambda which will act as a throttle when the queue explodes.
2. It guaranteers the lambda will always have capacity to run.  Note that it reduces your account capacity as well. Say if your account limit is 100 and your reserved concurrency for the lambda is 10.  Your new account limit is 90, but it is very easy to [increase you account limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36766553/aws-lambda-concurrent-request-limit-and-how-to-increase-that).

Setup:

1. Start by setting the reserved concurrency to something the database can easily handle.  Let's say you set it to reserved concurrency to 10, it takes 5 seconds for the lambda to load load the database, and you get max surge of 50 messages for 2 seconds.  It would take 50 seconds for you to empty the queue.  The math: (50 messages * 2) * 5 seconds / 10 lambdas = 50 seconds.
2. For the idle time you can set the reserved concurrency to 0 which will stop the Lambda's from running. To automate this you can create a CloudWatch Time Event that calls a Lambda that sets the Reserved Concurrency to 0 then another event that sets the Reserved Concurrency back to your limit.

Comment: I implemented the suggested solution and it's working brilliantly. It is a very smart approach, thank you.

Comment: @mauro Thank you for providing the feedback and glad it worked out for you.